Android Emulator has an error starting with code 1073741845
I'm working on a flutter project and using android emulator from android studio. At first it was working fine but then there's an error. Due to my project deadline I was using Chrome instead but using this I cannot test the mobile notification and other features.
At first it was saying maybe it is because of Riot Vanguard anticheat so I uninstall it and it still gives an error
Here's the error log
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code 1073741845 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] [25436:26424:20240604,214353.638:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [25436:26424:20240604,214353.638:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\66ba182b-ddee-467a-a3a8-236c8be8cc1d: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214353.805:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214353.805:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\66ba182b-ddee-467a-a3a8-236c8be8cc1d: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
[ERR] INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 827:9181:b002:0:80ef:9081:b002:0 (2x)
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\MY COM.android\avd..\avd\Pixel_7_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
[ERR] added library vulkan-1.dll
[ERR] [22768:14220:20240604,214354.802:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214354.809:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214354.809:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\342971b0-e0c2-4032-972b-d4399f87197c: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214354.811:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214354.811:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\342971b0-e0c2-4032-972b-d4399f87197c: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214354.811:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214357.703:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\9a3e0d68-0c64-47a1-8200-37509361c477: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [22768:15896:20240604,214357.703:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MYCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\342971b0-e0c2-4032-972b-d4399f87197c: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
